# twig attrbutes.addclass nesting issue

Tags: twig, drupal-8

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I'm on my first week working with Drupal and Twig.

I have the following code:

```
{%
  set container_classes = [
    'paragraph',
    'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
    view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    not paragraph.isPublished() ? 'paragraph--unpublished',
    'container'  
  ]  
%}
{% set image_classes = [
  'col-12'  
]
%}
{% block paragraph %}  
  
  {% block content %}
    <div{{ attributes.addClass(container_classes) }}>
      <div class='row'>
        <div{{ attributes.addClass(image_classes) }} data-type='image'>
          {{ content.field_two_column_image }}          
        </div>
        <div class='col-12 col-lg-auto' data-type='copy'>
          {{ content.field_two_column_copy }}
        </div>
      </div?>
    </div>          
  {% endblock %}
 
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

My issue is the nested `attributes.addClass`. When I look at the HTML, I'm also seeing the `container_classes` classes, which is not what I'm looking for.

So how can I separate the two?

Answer (score 0):

You can [Create Attributes in Twig](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates#s-create-attributes-in-twig).
Something like this should work.

```
{# attributes for container #}
{% set container_attributes = create_attribute() %}
{%
  set container_classes = [
    'paragraph',
    'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
    view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    not paragraph.isPublished() ? 'paragraph--unpublished',
    'container'  
  ]  
%}
{% set container_attributes = container_attributes.addClass(container_classes) %}

{# attributes for image #}
{% set image_attributes = create_attribute() %}
{% set image_classes = [
  'col-12'  
]
%}
{% set image_attributes = image_attributes.addClass(image_classes) %}

{% block paragraph %}  
  
  {% block content %}
    <div{{ container_attributes }}>
      <div class='row'>
        <div{{ image_attributes }} data-type='image'>
          {{ content.field_two_column_image }}          
        </div>
        <div class='col-12 col-lg-auto' data-type='copy'>
          {{ content.field_two_column_copy }}
        </div>
      </div?>
    </div>          
  {% endblock %}

{% endblock paragraph %}
```